# Access an array defined in an included file from the parent script

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

I'm looking for a way to access an array defined in an included PHP file, from outside this file. I've been Googling on that for a few hours but I didn't really find anything that answered my question.
I've tried using $GLOBAL['varname'] outside my script after using global $varname in the included file but it doesn't seem to work, got to say I'm a bit confused.

Is there any way I can do this in PHP?

Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user `$_SESSION` variables. so you will be able to access your variables **anywhere** in your php application.. untill you `unset` it..

try this..

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['array'] = $array; //your array
```

now you can use this variable/array in any file of your project..

```
print_r($_SESSION['array']);
```

Comment: Well thanks, that was the first solution I found to my problem, I was just wondering whether there was a better way of doing it, without using sessions. Anyway if this is the only way, then I'll stick to it, thank you!

Comment: Cookies can be an option...
and you can also `serialize` the array and put it in a `hidden field` and post it to another page.. and `unserialize` it.. but session is the best option..

Comment: Because its not the answer.... you can access any variable in an included file by using the variable name.

Comment: may be you havent read the question properly.. He told that he **want to access the array outside that file** @RaggaMuffin-420

Comment: Maybe YOU didnt read: "access an array defined in an included PHP file, from outside this file."  Hence the INCLUDED bit.. if the files been included... then its all good in the hood.

Comment: ohhh **he havent clarified that he wants to access that array in the particular file in which the another file is included**.. Please think twice before downvoting someone's answer. 
We are not here for competition to each other... so respect someone's efforts
@RaggaMuffin-420

Comment: I'm not trying to compete, but downvoting isn't for that reason, down voting is for incorrect answers, in this case I was in the right i believe.  thanks for your feedback though.

Comment: how can you say that this is an incorrect answer?? I have clarified all the things above..

Comment: there are many ways to do everything, that is the wrong way to do what the question was about. don't forget to upvote the correct answer ;)

Comment: It's okay guys, no need to fight here, the $_SESSION solution works just fine. My problem's solved :)

Comment: @Drav' can you please +1 my answer,,, Thanks

Comment: Sorry @NishantSolanki but I can't, it requires a reputation of 15 points but mine is currently of 10.

Answer (score 0):

if you include a file in PHP you can access the variable the same way you would if it was in the same file..

File1 (foo.php):

```
<?php
$var = array('foo','bar');
```

File2:

```
<?php
require_once('foo.php');
print_r($var);
```

does this not work..?